# How to get md5sum for online video without download

Tags: video, md5sum

I am using Ubuntu. Is it possible to check `md5sum` of a video using its URL?

In `man md5sum` :

```
md5sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

So no URL. Is there any way to check `md5sum`

Answer (score 1):

**Note: If just a symbol is changed in the file's content, md5sum will provide another result.**

It is impossible to do it on the fly, because `md5sum` is calculated by reading the file **from the beginning till the end** and to calculate it `md5sum` needs to have the file locally.

There are programs that calculates `md5sum` using its URL. But they will first download it and then calculate its `md5sum`.